# Overflow Scroll within a responsive layout

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

I have this layout:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="gallery">
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
        <div class="thumb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#container {
    background-color: black;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    margin:50px;
}
#sidebar {
    background-color: purple;
    min-width: 250px;
    width:250px;
    max-width: 20%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
#logo {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
#box {
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: grey;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    text-align: justify;
}
#content {
    display:inline;
    width:75%;
    margin-left: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#gallery {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
    background-color: blue;
}
.thumb {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 7px solid white;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I need the content of the `#box` and either `#gallery` or `#content` to be scrollable vertically.

Because my layout is responsible and the overflow of the #container is hidden I think there must be some problem with these features.

Here I created a [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDeUx/) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I've changed my answer ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in CSS #box

```
max-height : 100px ; /*for example*/
```

EDIT :

for you can use

```
overflow: auto;
```

in DIV you want to scroll

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't want a fixed height nor a max height in either the `#box` or the `#gallery`. It has to be responsive and stretch as long as the browser window goes.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on the jsFiddle I've linked and on my file. I can't see why.